# Check for regex in commit message using GitHub Actions

Tags: regex, bash, github-actions

I want to check for this particular regex in the commit messages for every push event
`/(user story|defect|quality story) #[0-9]+/gi`

The github action should echo 'Matching Expression' if the regex is found or exit if not found.

This is what I came up with:

```
name: 'Commit Message Standards Check'
on:
  push:

jobs:
  Commit_Message_Check:
    name: Commit Message Check
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{github.event_name == 'push' }}
    steps:
      - id: step1
        run: |
          if [ ${{ github.event.head_commit.message }} =~ /\(user story\|defect\|quality story\) #\[0-9]\+/gi ]; 
          then 
            echo "match=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          fi 
      - id: step2
        if: steps.step1.outputs.match == 'true'
        run: |
          echo "Matching Expressions"
      - id: step3
        if: steps.step1.outputs.match != 'true'
        run: exit 1
      - id: step4
        if: ${{ failure() && steps.step3.conclusion == 'failure' }}
        run: echo "Wrong Expression"
```

But this is the result I get [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHIPA.png)

Any sort of help will be much appreciated.

I tried changing the if statement in step 1 to the following

`if ${{ github.event.head_commit.message }} =~ /\(user story\|defect\|quality story\) #\[0-9]\+/gi ;`

`if [ ${{ github.event.head_commit.message }} =~ /\(user story\|defect\|quality story\) #\[0-9\]\+/gi ];`

`if [ ${{ github.event.head_commit.message }} =~ '/(user story|defect|quality story) #[0-9]+/gi' ];`

I was not able to fix it.

Comment: You should set the message as an environment variable to prevent [shell injection](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#understanding-the-risk-of-script-injections).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, a regex is not enclosed in slashes. Spaces outside of parentheses need to be backslashed or quoted.

To use the `=~` operator, you can't use the `[` builtin, you need the `[[` shell keyword.

To turn on case-insensitive matching, set the `nocasematch` shell option.

Testing in bash:

```bash
$ shopt -s nocasematch
$ if [[ "User Story #04" =~ (user story|defect|quality story)' '#[0-9]+ ]] ; then echo yes ; fi
yes
```

Also note that a regex doesn't have to match the whole string, so you probably need `^` at the beginning (and maybe a `$` at the end).